# How to connect to oracle db by using only host url in codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I have open port url `192.168.1.9` and its `username : test` and `password: test` of a oracle database How can i connect to the oracle database using this data and url in codeigniter?

Comment: Is there a specific problem? Have you read the documentation? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: @Madmartigan  check for oracle database connection its different something like this http://shrikantkinhikar.blogspot.in/2010/12/codeigniter-oracle-connection.html

Comment: I see, have you read this? (warning: from 2008): http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Oracle:Known_Issues/

Comment: What do you mean by "using only host url"?

Comment: @budwiser open port of oracle db i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it you will have to use [oci8 extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) with CI`s [oci8 driver](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/drivers/oci8/oci8_driver.php):

```
$config['hostname'] = '192.168.1.9/XE'; // assuming it is XE
$config['username'] = 'test';
$config['password'] = 'test';
$config['database'] = 'dbname';
$config['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
```

This _*should*_ work.

If you hoped to use PDO for it, then it is not possible. Mostly because of [pdo_oci](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php) driver's strangeness and disaster, that is CI's [database drivers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php).